Biasing common-source NMOS with active load and fixed Vgs
I came across this circuit, a common-source NMOS amplifier with PMOS current mirror as active load AND a fixed DC voltage level at the NMOS gate.

Since we're using a current mirror, we are, by extension, also biasing the amplifier using current (i.e. the Iref times the aspect-ratios quotient between the the current mirros PMOSes). On the other hand, if we have a fixed DC Vgs level, we are also biasing using a fixed Vgs, and in this case the source is tied to ground.
Given these facts and the fact that the drain current is Id = 2uCox(L/W)(Vgs-Vth)^2, doesn't the drain current generated by the DC Vgs comes into "conflict" with the current imposed by the current mirror (since the source voltage (GND) cannot change to shift Vgs to the "correct" level)?
I suspect it has something to do with the channel length modulation, i.e. the NMOS Vds would change to account for the incapacity of the Vgs to change level (since the full drain current formula also takes into account the channel length modulation, which is a function of Vds).

strange_bakery - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, edition etc. TY

Looks like a Razini diagram

@SamGibson I took it from an assignment from one of my university professors, on the assignment there's no reference from where it was taken from (and I'm VERY sure it wasn't the professor who drew it haha). I can make a diagram from scratch copying the design if necessary.

@D.A.S., Razini or Razavi?

Lol Razavi may Allah be merciful

Assuming that the potential at the top of M2 is \$V_{SUP}\$, and is greater than the sum of M1's and M2's combined \$V_{GS(TH)}\$, then it will be possible to have their drains at some mid-point potential \$\frac{V_{SUP}}{2}\$, and have both M1 and M2 simultaneously saturated. Then channel length modulation (CLM) would certainly be in play, and we must use an expression for drain current \$I_D\$ that accounts for it. The influence of CLM is represented by \$\lambda\$:
$$ I_D = \frac{1}{2}\mu _n C_{ox}\frac{W}{L} \left(V_{GS}-V_{TH} \right)^2(1 + \lambda V_{DS}) $$
Everything in that expression is constant except for the term \$\lambda V_{DS}\$, which seems to be the only mechanism present to relate a change in \$I_D\$ to a change in \$V_{DS}\$. If I replace all constant terms with \$K\$, the dependence of \$I_D\$ on \$V_{DS}\$ becomes clearer:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_D &= K(1 + \lambda V_{DS}) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
If there were no CLM, \$\lambda =0\$, then \$I_D\$ becomes constant too, \$ I_D = K \$, and no amount of change of \$V_{DS}\$ would change \$I_D\$. The consequence of this might be clearer in terms of the source's effective impedance, the ratio of change in \$V_{DS}\$ to the resulting change in \$I_D\$:
$$ r=\frac{\Delta V_{DS}}{\Delta I_D} $$
In the absence of CLM, \$I_D\$ remains fixed regardless of a change in \$V_{DS}\$:
$$ r=\frac{\Delta V_{DS}}{0A} = \infty \Omega $$
That's the behaviour you would expect from an ideal current source, with infinite impedance, in which case there really would be a conflict between an ideal source, and an ideal sink, in series.
My claim, then, is that you are correct. CLM is the chief mechanism by which these current sources and sinks do not have infinite impedance, are not ideal, and by which drain current can be coerced somewhat. Source impedance is still extremely high, though, and \$V_{DS}\$ will undergo huge changes as a result of even the slightest fluctuation of \$I_D\$.
I've also read of "Drain-Induced Barrier Lowering" (DIBL) which has some influence, not accounted for in the expression for \$I_D\$ above, but it seems to be neglected in most texts on the subject. I assume it really is negligible, for most intents and purposes, including this one, but you should be aware that it may also contribute to non-infinite impedance of a MOSFET employed as a current source/sink. To what extent, I do not know.
I'm sure there must be other factors contributing to the non-ideality of MOSFET-based current sources and sinks, but I am not aware of them, and like DIBL, I believe they will be insignificant compared to CLM.

I claim this answer is false because it avoids the assumptions on Vgs. It is the saturation boundary where the conflict occurs. CLM is not always chief.

@D.A.S. I concede that M1 and M2 are not "deeply" saturated, because at best $V_{GS}$ only marginally exceeds $V_{TH}$. They are saturated though. I concede that my argument depends on the $\lambda V_{DS}$ term being present and dominant in this only-just-saturated state, which may indeed be an unwarranted assumption.

If it is saturated  then Vds drops near zero  along with your Lambda effect and Io = Iref. The triode gain is so high the saturation threshold is not soft.

@D.A.S. Do we agree that 1) saturation is the state $V_{DS}>V_{GS}-V_{TH}$ and $V_{GS}>V_{TH}$, and 2) in saturation the graph of $I_D$ as a function of $V_{DS}$ has slope $\lambda I_D$?


No, 2 yes   No that is the Border that starts "near-off Vgs=Vgs(th) Vds at Id <= 1/1000 rated I max continuous. Saturation diverges and follows the square law where ΔId/ΔVgs changes most but ΔVds/ΔId is low RdsOn and with Vds near zero in this case. Did I describe what you imagine?  With high Id values Vgs can be 150% of Vgs(th) and still in Triode region.


@D.A.S. I have some thinking to do. Let me ponder point 1 before I comment further, and thank you for engaging with me on this.

I tried my sim again and thought about a criteria for saturation is gain change or end of linear mode, so I agree on 1. Is good.    But Vgs is still the dominant regulator where this cct is useful. Hence the question forgets to assume  it is in saturation mode with CLM  effects by choice of Vgs and Vgs rising above Vgs-Vgs.  the other proof is the 2nd derivative of Id wrt Vgs

@D.A.S. You had me scratching my head for while there. Anyway, I understood from the question that the asker was looking for insight regarding the apparent conflict between current sources in series, and in that context my answer does not consider modulation of M1's $V_{GS}$ at all, which is an oversight on my part. The question's schematic does have a voltage source modulating $V_{GS}$, though, and I understand that this renders my argument somewhat moot. In this context I totally agree with you.

@D.A.S. in saturation mode the Vds doesn't drop to zero, pretty much the other way around. If it were to drop to zero, then we would be in triode region. Remember that in MOSFET the saturation region is the active region (the opposite nomenclature of BJTs).

TY @strange_bakery I must be dyslexic or it’s Murphy’sLaw playing tricks with old memory. If anything can be inverted, or backward it will be.

@D.A.S. During our exchanges, I was forced to revisit stuff from 3 decades ago. I wish I could just have the head I had back then! Still, in spite of the inconvenience of my poor memory, it's kind of fun being pushed to recover lost stuff, and I'm grateful for the debate.

If that was the actual, complete circuit, yes, you are correct.  To function in that circuit the VGS "DC" source has to track the NMOS Vth over temperature and process.
This is most likely an idealized second stage of a basic operational amplifier circuit.  The VDC and vdc would be replaced by a NMOS transistor matched to M1 by W,L, and layout location.  This transistor would driven by one output of a differential pair.
Driving M1 with a current that has a DC bias and AC signal takes care of all the biasing problems with VDC and M1.   The differential pair would be driven with a tail current that is nominally 2x Io.  Any mismatch between the diff pair tail current and Io would be show up as an offset voltage in the differential pair.

I read the question as "Does fixed Vgs conflict with current mirror biasing in a MOSFET amplifier?"
Answers:
Yes but the mechanism depends on the Iref & NMOS\$V_{GS}\$ for 3 operating modes of;

Cutoff  ( zero bias (current) threshold = \$V_{GS}<=V_T\$

Triode ( High AC gain mode with Id controlled by Vgs)

Saturation Low Vgs gain mode with Io=Iref= constant Vds

The conflict is only significant at the border of 2. & 3.


An implied question is "Is CLM the cause of bias-current changes in Iout from changes in Vds?"
My answer is there are large and small channel effect variations that act as a leakage resistor called \$r_o\$.
In the triode region, it is typically 50 kohm at 1 mA.  This is also called the Lambda factor or "channel length modulation factor" in the Shichman-Hodges model.   \$r_o​=\dfrac{∂I_D}{​∂V_{DS}}​​=\dfrac{1}{λI_{D​}}\$. This effect reduces the AC gain,  as it loads the ideal infinite resistance of the current-mirror PFETs.
In the Saturation mode, RdsOn is sufficiently low to allow Id=Iref from the current source from the Level 0 equation, \$Id=\dfrac{\beta(V_{GS}{-V_T})^2}{2}\$ used in the Falstad web simulator with my interactive live design and sliders for all variables.
Conclusion
My key takeaway is in the triode region, Vgs by far is the major control of Id and not CLM. In the saturation region, Iref is the only control Id.  The boundary between these regions is the only area of conflict.
Side notes:

Real-world properties: MOSFET datsheets use \$V_{gs(th)}\$ at \$I_D\$= __ is chosen by Mfg. I call this the "near-off bias-current threshold". All datasheets show Id and it is <=0.1% of the "rated Id" or >= 1k times the "rated RdsOn".
When the DC bias on Vgs is in Saturation mode, Vds = Id*RdsOn is near 0 if Id << Imax and Iref controls this Iout current.
This circuit is imposible to use without negative feedback but then may be enhanced to be useful.
Don't forget that commercial MOSFETS have about a 2:1 range in Vgs(th)

Refs:

NanoDotTech https://web.archive.org/web/20120617082916/http://www.nanodottek.com/NDT14_08_2007.pdf  The Shichman-Hodges Enhancement MOSFET Model and SwitcherCAD III SPICE
CH. Length Modulation derivation in 10 minutes  https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?q=Large%20Channel%20Length%20Modulation%20(%CE%BB%CE%BB):&mid=B5EE503786DEE7B0BFF0B5EE503786DEE7B0BFF0&ajaxhist=0
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_short-channel_effect

Falstad’s sim allowed to create a plot of the conflict between Id and Vgs.
The Iref mirror controls the current limit if we ignore “ro” effects set to 5mA plotted by a Isense amp in y-axis and Vgs in x—axis.  Below you clearly see the plot of 3 modes of FET operation in quadrant 1(+,+) namely Off, triode, saturated (to Id max= const. current, CC = Iref)

The odd thing is calling the triode region “linear mode” as it is clearly quadratic up to Id=Iref.
Bonus Conflict
If we neglect lambda induced “ro”, and bias Vgs at the optimal Vd midpoint and with Iref=1mA =Id max, with no load, What is the AC gain ? Aol=GmRo or infinite?
What is it?

Seeing conflicts in circuits

... doesn't the drain current generated by the DC Vgs comes into "conflict" with the current imposed by the current mirror...?

I am pleasantly surprised that you see "conflicts" in circuits. The same idea occurred to me back in the 90s. Later, I dedicated two articles to it - one for "moderate" conflicts, and the other for "dramatic" conflicts between current and voltage sources. The reaction of participants in a related forum is indicative of how people perceive such a different approach to presenting circuit phenomena.
Revealing the basic idea
In the full circuit...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
... the drain-source parts of the transistors M2 and M3 connected in series can be considered as a dynamic voltage divider...

simulate this circuit

R2 = 5 kΩ, R3 = 5 kΩ: ... consisting of two dynamic resistors R2 and R3.

simulate this circuit
R2 = 9 kΩ, R3 = 1 kΩ: When the increasing input voltage Vin causes R3 to decrease, R2 increases so that the sum R2 + R3 remains relatively constant.

simulate this circuit
R2 = 1 kΩ, R3 = 9 kΩ: When the decreasing input voltage Vin causes R3 to increase, R2 decreases to keep the sum R2 + R3 relatively constant.

simulate this circuit
As a result, the current remains nearly unchanged, while the voltage changes dramatically.
Graphical representation
We can graphically represent the circuit's operation by superimposing the two IV curves (of the drain-source sections) onto each other. A geometric effect is produced: two nearly horizontal lines intersect, and one of them (M3's) moves in a vertical direction. As a result, the intersection (operating) point moves rapidly in a horizontal direction (high gain).


Interesting presentation. These were similar to XY plots I tried to make in Falstad with a family of VI plots by sliding Iref, but I didn’t know how to record it as a gif file.  I wish I had these tools in the ‘70’s ;)

You could have shown the conflict with the parts shown which are mismatched to get Vdd/2 by tolerances of Vth0  aka Vt or Vgs(th) or

@D.A.S., The situation gets even more intriguing when changing Iref in the opposite direction. In this case, the M2's curve shifts in a direction opposite to the M3's curve. This is a good illustration of a CMOS stage.

@D.A.S., Changing the threshold voltage Vth (up to zero) is a clever trick, thanks! I'll add it to my CircuitLab bag of tricks (I use CircuitLab as a general term for a simulator). It would be interesting to change simultaneously both Vth's in a CMOS stage to show the three possible cases. But why isn't there such an option for VF in BJT? I would use it to set a zero VF voltage (an "ideal" transistor).

Did you catch my Bonus Conflict?

@D.A.S.To be frank, I'm lost.

If we are very strict, this circuit isn't biased at all. For example, can you tell me what the drain voltage of this transistor will be? It is not well-defined. Put a signal at the gate and the drain voltage will swing all over the place.
And you are right, there would be a conflict because, as any sane designer would do, drain current and voltage are defined first, and then you let a negative feedback loop take care of the controlling variables (gate voltage and current, if any).
A while back I answered about how an interesting amplifier was biased with local negative feedback at every stage. If you understand that, hopefully you'll get closer to understanding how an amplifier is properly biased.
As a former professor of mine used to joke (more or less): "you can't force a current through a mosfet drain."

Yes you can force a current thru a FET with a current limiter or mirror and sufficient Vgs. -1  of course his assumption was neglecting biased saturation. When it is just a resistor

@D.A.S. the question is, is it biased? Of course not. Obviously the last statement was made with the purpose of biasing.

Designalog, The circuit is biased (look at Schematic 1.1 in my answer). But the gain is high and the operating point is unstable.

@Circuitfantasist "the circuit is biased" but the "operating point is unstable", ergo, it's not biased ;)

Designalog, maybe you mean "properly biased"...

@Circuitfantasist thing is, I don't disagree with your answer, it's actually correct. My answer was more intended towards biasing due to the title in the question. In my opinion, a biased circuit has every node well defined even in the presence of an AC signal.

@Circuitfantasist Designers define the drain and current voltages, and let the loop defined that gate voltages and current needed, much like the diode-connected transistor does to drive the gate of another transistor (a current mirror, though this is indirect feedback I must admit). That's why I'm wary about drawing schematics the way that textbook figure does it, as it leads to the confusion the OP has. Arguing about differences between "biased" and "properly biased", to me, is an uninteresting discussion to have.

Designalog, We need to be precise in our terminology. The 4.02V input voltage is a 'bias' voltage, designed to overcome the transistor's threshold voltage. The varying input voltage is added to this constant voltage. The problem lies in the high amplification of both the bias voltage and the input voltage. We need to employ some tricks to make the amplification of the bias voltage small and the amplification of the input voltage large. One such trick is separating the two voltages using capacitors in AC amplifiers. Another trick is suppressing common-mode signals in differential amplifiers...
